# What causes these spikes in freed memory?

Tags: c#, virtual-memory

[image: Chart of available virtual memory in bytes]

This is a chart of available virtual memory, in bytes, for a small application I'm prototyping with. The application runs in a tight loop which adds an integer to the end of a linked list. If there is a certain percentage of virtual memory remaining it goes to the beginning of the loop, otherwise it exits. What is causing the sudden increases in virtual memory at those six places in the graph? My first thought was garbage collection, but since I'm adding new elements to the linked list without deleting any there shouldn't be any unused references to clean up, certainly not in those large amounts. The final jump is over a third of a gigabyte. This is an application compiled for x86 but running on an x64 machine under .NET 4.5. Sorry if this is a duplicate, I don't know what to call the event so it's hard to search for it.

Edit: I can't provide the exact code but this code does demonstrate what I'm seeing.

```
public void DoIt()
{
    ComputerInfo ci = new ComputerInfo();
    double memory = 0;
    double count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i ++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ci.AvailableVirtualMemory);
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                list.AddFirst(892);
                count++;
            }
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryException)
        {
            memory = ci.AvailableVirtualMemory;
            list.Clear();
            list = null;
            System.GC.Collect();
            list = new LinkedList<int>();
            Console.WriteLine(memory);
            Console.WriteLine(count);
            count = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post code that reproduces the issue? Without code, one can only speculate.

Comment: There's always garbage being produced, even for small temporary objects. Most likely it is these that keep adding up and then being freed. You should track when GC occurs and I'm pretty sure you would see a correlation between this and the spikes. Also, consider showing a graph of *used* memory instead of *available* memory since this is the norm in questions like these and the graph you posted seems to be quite the opposite of the norm.

Comment: How are you calculating the percentage of virtual memory remaining? That, to me, seems like a potential for resources being loaded and cleaned up by the GC. Especially since you do it on every iteration.

Comment: @Rob Outside of the loop I store the initial amount of VMem available. Then every iteration I check `origVMemAvailable * <some percent>` against `ci.AvailableVirtualMemory`.

Comment: does `AvailableVirtualMemory` consume some objects and memory during its calculations each iteration?

Comment: @stephen.vakil I don't know. It's a property of the ComputerInfo (part of Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices) class.